# How to solve the error "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer"

Tags: java, eclipse

I made the code below, but when I tried to run "ClassSample", error written below appeared.
How can I solve this error?

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor in both module jrt.fs and module java.base

Also, this is the image of my package explorer.

[image]

```
package Java_Practice.chapter3;

public class ClassSample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Cat taro = new Cat("太郎", 3);
        Cat mike = new Cat("ミケ", 5);
        Cat tama = new Cat("タマ", 4);
 
        Cat[] cats = {taro, mike, tama};
 
        for(Cat cat : cats) {
            cat.shout();
            cat.introduce();
        }

        System.out.println("今までに作成したCatインスタンスの数: " + Cat.count);
 
    }
    
}
```

```
package Java_Practice.chapter3;

public class Cat {

    public static int count = 0;
 
    public String name;
    public int age;
 
    public Cat(String name, int age){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        Cat.count++;   
    }
 
    public void shout() {
        System.out.println("にゃー!");
    }
 
    public void introduce() {
        System.out.println("名前は" + this.name + "、" + this.age + "才です。");
        this.shout();
    }

}
```

What I'm expecting :

run the code without error.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your project settings, with the configuration of the installed JREs, or your Java installation: the system library or a part of it seems to be added as dependency twice. Please show what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ (search for nodes with names containing `jrt`) and what you have in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_. An uncropped screenshot of the _Package Explorer_ showing the project structure and the dependencies might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
Could you check if this screenshot below is the thing that you were mentioning?
http://imepic.jp/20230328/481340